# How do add/integrate SqlMembershipProvider in existing MVC 3 project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sqlmembershipprovider

On creating a new MVC project, Visual Studio take cares of `SqlMembershipProvider` if it is a non-empty project. Visual Studio creates a Database and all necessary Tables.

But, I have an existing MVC 3 project and I would like to add/integrate `SqlMembershipProvider`.

How can I add `SqlMembershipProvider` and create all needed Tables in my existing Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

```
Aspnet_regsql.exe   ( this creates the necessary tables into your existing database)
```

Take a look here:
[What's difference between windows and forms authentication in asp.net mvc 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842274/whats-difference-between-windows-and-forms-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-4/15845541#15845541)

YES, ignore the sections of code that refer to comparison for windows and forms authentication. However, it should serve as useful information on SQLMembershipProvider which uses the Membership and MembershipUser classes to provide these membership services to a ASP.NET application.

Aspnet_regsql.exe

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers) nuget package

> ASP.NET Universal Providers add provider support in ASP.NET 4 for all
>   editions of SQL Server 2005 and later and to SQL Azure. If you use
>   these providers to develop your application, the application will be
>   ready for cloud environments like Azure. Other than supporting
>   additional storage options, the providers work like the existing
>   SQL-based providers, so that you can easily switch an application to
>   use cloud storage via SQL Azure.

And for [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) great Hanselman's post

> The configuration for these providers is the same as the existing
>   SqlMembershipProvider class, but the type parameter is set to the type
>   of the new providers, as shown in the following table:
>
> SQL Provider Types    -> Equivalent Type for Universal Providers
>   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider
>   ->    System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider
>   ->    System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider
>   ->    System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider (Built in provider)    System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider

Comment: Well, my current project dont have Any membership added, and adding news is getting a little hard.

Comment: I have add not swap with any existing!

Comment: Yep, I meant this for adding, not for swapping... did you try to add the package? If it doesn't meet your needs you can easily rollback...